# kex_exchange_identification error after upgrading to debian10 from debian9

Tags: linux, debian, ssh

I am performing a manual upgrade on a `Debian 9` machine to `Debian 10`. This takes place on a GCP VM.

I have an image of the VM, so the process is repeatable.

After the upgrade and since I have been prompted the regarding the `/etc/ssh` to install the maintainer's file and or keep the current one (I have tried both) the `ssh` process fails with:

```
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by 11.223.44.55 port 22
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

try to run `ssh -v` to have a deeper look.  What kind of client is used (`ssh` from OpenSSH?). Newer versions have outdated algorithms and so disabled by default. PuTTY has a lot of old algorithms enabled by default. Try to use PuTTY as SSH client. If it works with PuTTY, try to identify what kind of algorithm is the source for the problem

Comment: I am using MacOS client

Comment: Specifically `OpenSSH_9.0p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6`

Comment: OpenSSH 9 is a recent version and I also had the situation, that some connections need some tweaks. Can you perform a diff of the sshd configuration file, it means, what was changed during the update?